# get Schema for Solr Server using Java to find Copy Fields

Tags: java, solr, get, schema

I am trying to use Java to get the fields in a Solr DB that are copyfields as well as their destination. Is there a way to grab the schema from within Java for a Solr DB by using the server? I would prefer not to hardcode the filepath to the schema file as it will change.

I know that the Solr Admin page does "file?file=schema.xml&contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8" to give you your schema but I'm not sure if that's a query.

Like, if I were to say SolrQuery q = new SolrQuery(admin/file?file=schema.xml&contentType=text/xml:charset=utf-8') and then do QueryResponse schema = server.query(q), I don't think QueryResponse would hold the xml file would it?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly fire an http request to get the schema file and parse the same.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/collection1/admin/file?file=schema.xml&contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8
```

This can be made dynamic just by replacing the core name e.g. collection1 in the above url